# Sequence And Series - How To Find The Limit Of A Converging Sequence With No Common Ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series

3/2, 4/3, 5/4, 6/5....

The nth term of the sequence could be expressed as $\frac{n+2}{n+1}$.

I can't seem to work out how to get the limit of the function, as most of the books describe the sum of a geometric series to infinity as

$$ \ S = \frac{a}{1 -r} $$

With a = 3/2 and being the first term, I am confused as to what r should be equal to, as this sequence does not seem to have a common ratio. I thought that there should be some r that would have been the common ratio.

Maybe I am going down the wrong line of thinking, so please clarify how to find the limit and the value of r for the equation.

Many Thanks

Comment: You’re confusing sequences and series in your terminology. Are you talking about the **sequence** $\frac32,\frac43,\frac54,\dots$ whose $n$-th term is $\frac{n+2}{n+1}$, or are you talking about a **series**, an infinite sum of terms?

Comment: Yes, that maybe because I am a little confused.  I am talking about the sequence.  And how to find the limit.. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the $n$-th term of a certain sequence is $\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}$.  Note that 
$$\frac{n+2}{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{n+1}.$$
 As $n\to\infty$, the $\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ part approaches $0$, so our limit is $1$.

Or else we can divide top and bottom by $n$, obtaining
$$\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\frac{1+\frac{2}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}.$$
As $n\to\infty$, $1+\dfrac{2}{n}\to 1$, and $1+\dfrac{1}{n}\to 1$, so our limit is $1$.

**Remark:** One can get useful information from the calculator. If you are interested in finding the limit as $n\to\infty$ of $a_n$, you can calculate $a_n$ for a few largish $n$. For example, ca;culate $\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}$ for $n=1000$ and for $n=10000$. It will now be plausible that the limit might be $1$. And once one knows that the "answer" should be $1$, it becomes easier to show that it is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am still confused as to how how we find the limit, but I think I may be able to work it out from your answer

Comment: Also, when you say the limit is 1, do you mean that the sequence will never rise above zero.. thanks.. I am teaching myself mathematics, so I find some things confusing

Comment: When one says that the limit is $1$, one is saying, informally, that when $n$ is very big then $\frac{n+2}{n+1}$ is awfully close to $1$.

Comment: thank you, so much. I actually understand what going on a little better now

Answer (score 0):

For all when $x$ approches infinity 
1) If degree is equal on up and down then answer will be equal to the divison of both(up nd down) with constants.
Example. $\lim_{x\to\inf\frac{n+2}{n+1}}$
both up nd down are power with $1$ then $1/1=1$

2). If degree of variable is greater on up than degree of down then answer will be $+$ or minus infinity.

3). If degree of variable is less on up than degree of down then answer will be zero.

Answer (score -1):

for a seaquency Un..a limit L is such that for its value there is a positive integer N such that n>N..so a sequency only has this limit L if there are still some integer values of n falling in this lane

Comment: It's difficult to grasp what you mean about sequences and "values of n falling in this lane".  This is an older Question, so don't rush your Answer.  See the [Help Center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) for how to write good Answers, and be aware that this site allows the use of LaTeX formatting via [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).